# Do virtual hosts in Apache require the "FollowSymLinks" option to be enabled?

Tags: server, apache2, symbolic-link, virtualhost

In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, I have the following configuration for Apache with regard to the `/var/www` directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf` then, this is how I've set up my virtual host for `example.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything is working fine so far.

But as soon as I edit the `<Directory /var/www/>` part (see above) from

```
Options -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI
```

to

```
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```

the website stops working and responds with a `403` error instead.

Why is this happening? Nowhere did I use any symbolic links, at least not consciously. So is Apache using them internally when working with virtual hosts?

I don't see any reason why that option should break the setup. The website is actually stored in `/var/www/example.com/public`, that's not a symbolic link, either.

Comment: You can use `sudo find /var/www -type l` to be sure. And look at your error log.

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks, that helped! Should have looked that up right away, of course. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

The Apache error logs explain the reason for this problem:

> [rewrite:error] [pid ...] [client ...] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions

Using `mod_rewrite` with `RewriteRule` (as is common) while *disabling* `FollowSymLinks` (as shown in the question) is only possible if `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` is *enabled* in return.

Thus

```
-FollowSymLinks
```

must become

```
-FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

*or* `mod_rewrite` with `RewriteRule` cannot be used anymore.

Thanks for the hint, @fkraiem!